# angular2 async http requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular

May be I don't understand how async requests should work, but from my point of view 1 ajax or 10 should took almost the same time to be finished. Right now I'm facing a problem, I'm sending 3 ajax requests at the same time, and it took about 3 seconds for the first ajax, 15 seconds for the second, and 18 for the last. But if I send only first ajax - it's took 3 seconds, only second - 15 seconds, only third - 1 second. So, in other words it doesn't matter if I send 3 ajax together

```
this.contractService.saveContractsForOpportunity(selectedContracts).subscribe(data => {

});
this.contractService.saveContractsForOpportunity(selectedContracts).subscribe(data => {

});
this.contractService.saveContractsForOpportunity(selectedContracts).subscribe(data => {

});
```

Or if I send it one by one like this

```
this.contractService.saveContractsForOpportunity(selectedContracts).subscribe(data => {
    this.contractService.saveContractsForOpportunity(selectedContracts).subscribe(data => {
       this.contractService.saveContractsForOpportunity(selectedContracts).subscribe(data => {

       }); 
    });        
});
```

It tooks the same time to be finished
[image]

May be it's only about backend or server configuration?

Comment: first case total time is 18 seconds, and almost the same for the second case (18-19 seconds)

Comment: session_write_close is the answer on my question. PHP will lock session files for each request and maintain that lock until you do a session_write_close(). Looks like I have to put it in every php script to get it work

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your problem lies on the server side. Does the server allow handling multiple requests from the same IP in parallel?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm using apache2 out from the box, how can I check?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for directing me to the right way